# Auto Login using MOBAxterm

Tags: shell, terminal, telnet, putty

I am facing issues writing a script in Mobaxterm to automate my logins. The expect script doesn't seem to work quite well.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet <IP address>
expect -re "login"
send "username\n"
expect -re "Password"
send "password of the user\n"
interact
```

**Scenario:**
The infrastructure of my company requires me to ssh into a jump server and only then can i telnet into cisco routers. 
So my log in would look like this if I had to do it through CLI:

> ssh x.x.x.x
>   telnet y.y.y.y
>   *******Company banner********
>   NOC : username
>   Password : password

Kindly help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the Answer is late and you might have found the solution but posting my solution just in case it helps someone in future :

For the Already Created Session which you want to Automate :

1. Right Click on the session & Go to "Edit Session" > SSH > Advanced SSH Settings > Execute Macros At Session Start > "Select Custom Macro"
2. Configure the Setting in the below manner (I wanted to Automate For Docker hence the configuration below - It will change depending upon your host IP's/password etc) :

[image]

Comment: WAITFOR=password - did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

You can also click the record macro button and type out what you want then save the macro. That's a lot faster than hand-typing your own custom macro. Works right away without having to debug the macro you hand wrote.